# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Collection' not found in

Tags: php, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-api

Estoy trabajando en un código PHP que me permita leer la información de las tablas "Google Sheets", y al ejecutarlo en local host ( XAMPP ) me suelta este error.

***"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Collection' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Service\Sheets\Sheet.php:18 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(7): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Service\Sheets\Sheet.php on line 18"***

Las rutas a los archivos las tengo bien puestas ( las comprobé mas de una vez ), no se que más puede ser.

**Adjunto mis lineas de código hasta el momento:**

```
<?php

require_once ""C:/xampp\htdocs\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Client.php"";
require_once "C:/xampp\htdocs\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Service\Sheets\Sheet.php";

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setClientId("XXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com");
$client->setClientSecret("XXXXXXXXXXX");
$client->setRedirectUri("XXXXX");

$sheets_service = new Google_Service_Sheets_Sheet($client);

$url = $client->createAuthUrl();

?>


<a href="<?php echo $url;?>">Login</a>
```

Comment: Tienes dos comillas, debes dejar solamente una, así: `require_once "C:/xampp\htdocs\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Client.php";` Debes verificar, por supuesto, que ese archivo existe ahí y que la clase se llama así.

Comment: Hola, ya probé cambiándolo y el error sigue apareciendo. El archivo existe y esta en esa ruta.
Muchas gracias igualmente por la respuesta!

Comment: ¿Usaste `Composer` para instalar la librería PHP de Google? Suena a que faltan archivos de la librería.

Comment: Si yo estoy pensando que puede venir por ahí. Pero no se como resolverlo. 
Quise probar "trayendo" composer a mi PHP pero no encuentro la linea de código para hacerlo.

Perdón por la falta de información y conocimiento, recién comienzo a trabajar con PHP. Y muchas gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: Pues borrando las carpetas donde están las clases de la API e instalando de nuevo con `Composer`, como indica Google ( [ver aquí](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) ), el comando es este: `composer require google/apiclient:"^2.0"`
.  Y la forma de inclusión es más sencilla, no tienes que hacer varios require, sino solamente este: `require_once '/ruta/a/tu-proyecto/vendor/autoload.php';` Ya está. Autoload se encarga de poner cualquiera de las clases de la API en el contexto.

Comment: Ahora cuando cargo el local host me tira un error de sintaxis:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'require' (T_REQUIRE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 3

es la linea del codigo :
composer require google/apiclient:"^2.0"

Comment: ¿Instalaste la librería con Composer? ¿La instalación fue correcta? ¿Qué error tira ahora?

Comment: La instalación salio con éxito. La computadora detecta el composer instalado.
solo tira el error de sintaxis que te envié en el comentario anterior.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon como tienes el código. Debe ser un caracter mal puesto o algo así. Una cosa: esto `composer require google/apiclient:"^2.0"` no va en tu archivo PHP. Eso debes ejecutarlo en la consola PHP una sola vez para que te instale la librería. ¿Queda claro?

Comment: Ya logre arreglarlo. Tenia mal un paso en la instalación del composer, lo tenia instalado en la consola general y no en la ubicación del index.

Ahora tengo que ver con que código de PHP puedo traer el scope ( me lo pide en la autorizacion de Auth ).

Muchas Gracias por las respuestas y el tiempo!

Comment: @Manuel Considera publicar la solución como respuesta